# Saving Django AJAX comments

Tags: json, ajax, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm adding AJAX comments to my Django project, but the comments are not saved. Could you please tell me where I have a mistake?

This is AJAX file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#comment-form').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check
    create_comment();
});
function create_comment() {
    console.log("create comment is working!")
    $.ajax({
        url: "/friends_plans/new_comment/",
        type: "POST",
        headers: {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")},
        data: {text: $('#comment-text').val(), wish_list_id: $('#wish_list_id').val()},
        success: function (json) {
            $('#comment-text').val('');
            console.log(json);
            $("#comments").append('<div class="row"><div class="panel panel-default"><div class="panel-body">'+json.text+'</p><p style="float: right">'+json.person+', &nbsp</p></div></div><br>');
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("some erors!");
        }
    });
};
function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
        c_start = document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=");
        if (c_start != -1) {
            c_start = c_start + c_name.length + 1;
            c_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", c_start);
            if (c_end == -1) c_end = document.cookie.length;
            return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start, c_end));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
});
```

This is function from views.py:

```
def new_comment(request):
form = Comment_to_wish_listForm(request.POST)
print ("function1")
if form.is_valid():
    print ("function2")
    data = request.POST.copy()
    wish_list_id = data['wish_list_id']
    text = data['text']
    wish_list = Wish_list.objects.get(id=wish_list_id)
    comment = Comment_to_wish_list(text=text, comment_to=wish_list, person=request.user)
    comment.save()
    response_data = {}
    response_data['text'] = comment.text
    response_data['person'] = comment.person.username
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response_data),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
return render(request, 'friends_plans/index.html', {})
```

This is part of template:

```
            ...
            <h3> Comments </h3>
            {% if message %}
                <p style="color:red">{{ message }}</p>
            {% endif %}
            <div id="comments">
                {% for comment_to_wish_list in wish_list.comment_to_wish_list_set.all %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    {{ comment_to_wish_list.text }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <p style="float: right"> {{ comment_to_wish_list.person }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <form id="comment-form" action="/new_comment/{{wish_list.id }}/" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="form-group">
                        {{ form.text }}
                        <input type="text" name="text" id="comment-text" placeholder="Text" width="250" height="50" value="">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="wish_list_id" id="wish_list_id" value="{{ wish_list.id }}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="create-comment" id="create-comment" value="Create">
                    </div>
                </form>
            {% else %}
                <p>Log in or register! </p>
            {% endif %}
            ...
```

This is URL:

```
url(r'^new_comment/$', views.new_comment, name="new_comment")
```

Everything is ok with POST method. I can see the message from `print ("function1")`, but no message from `print ("function2")`, and the comment is not saved. Another problem is that the function from AJAX file is called twice, I can't understand why.

Comment: Can you check the form errors ?

Comment: Your function gets called twice because your submit event gets fired twice, as for the code in the view, check for form errors. If you have a clean method called on form check that as well

Comment: Thanks a lot! I checked form errors, i had 2 more required fields in the form: likes and views. Now the comments are saved! But I don't understand the explanation about colling the function twice. It seems to me I do this only once, in the 2 line in AJAX file: `...on('submit', function (event)...` Could you please explain what is wrong and what I need to change?